Is the Gradle configuration cache broken?
My Android app is configured to use the Gradle configuration cache. I recently upgraded Android Studio to Koala, Gradle from 8.6 to 8.7, and the Gradle plugin from 8.4.2 to 8.5.2, and building the app now fails with:
Configuration cache problems found in this build.

1 problem was found storing the configuration cache.
- Task `:app:compileDebugKotlin` of type `org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile`: invocation of 'Task.project' at execution time is unsupported.
See https://docs.gradle.org/8.7/userguide/configuration_cache.html#config_cache:requirements:use_project_during_execution

The referenced documentation, IIUC, explains how to properly design tasks to work with the configuration task - but this error doesn't seem to be related to a task that I've written (I haven't written any), but to something created by Android Studio. Turning off the configuration cache fixes the problem.
Am I doing something wrong, or is the configuration cache just not compatible with the Gradle / Android Studio versions I'm using?
